# Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop for <View> not working react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a list for user details, in that for parent container I have given `<View key={details.id}>` an it is unique. But I loaded the page it always throws `Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.`. Also the `TextInput` fields are not editable. Wher am going wrong. Please have a look into my code.

```
{this.state.profileDetails.map(details => {
                            return (
                                <View key={details.id}>
                                    <Text style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>
                                        <Image
                                            style={styles.imageCircle}
                                            source={require('../../../../assets/sample.jpeg')}
                                        />
                                    </Text>
                                    <View>
                                        <Text style={{marginBottom: 5}}>First Name:</Text>
                                        <TextInput
                                            style={styles.textEdit}
                                            value={details.first_name}
                                            onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({first_name:text})}
                                        />
                                        <Text style={{marginBottom: 5}}>Last Name:</Text>
                                        <TextInput
                                            style={styles.textEdit}
                                            value={details.last_name}
                                        />
                                        <Text style={{marginBottom: 5}}>Title:</Text>
                                        <TextInput
                                            style={styles.textEdit}
                                            value={details.designation}
                                        />
                                        <Text style={{marginBottom: 5}}>Firm:</Text>
                                        <TextInput
                                            style={styles.textEdit}
                                            value={details.firm}
                                        />
                                        <Text style={{marginBottom: 5}}>Email Address:</Text>
                                        <TextInput
                                            style={styles.textEdit}
                                            value={details.email}
                                        />
                                        <Text style={{marginBottom: 5}}>Work Number:</Text>
                                        <TextInput
                                            style={styles.textEdit}
                                            value={details.work_number}
                                        />
                                        <Text style={{marginBottom: 5}}>Cell Number:</Text>
                                        <TextInput
                                            style={styles.textEdit}
                                            value={details.cell_number}
                                        />
                                        <Text style={{marginBottom: 5}}>LinkedIn Profile:</Text>
                                        <TextInput
                                            style={styles.textEdit}
                                            value={details.linkedin_profile}
                                        />
                                        <Text style={{marginBottom: 5}}>Summary:</Text>
                                        <TextInput
                                            multiline={true}
                                            numberOfLines={4}
                                            style={styles.textEdit}
                                            value={details.about}
                                        />
                                    </View>
                                </View>
                            )
                        })}
```

Is there any solution to bypass this issue. Please guide me through.

Comment: Check if `details.id` is `undefined`

Comment: @AsafAviv It is defined. Its value is `1`

Comment: most probably there are multiple items with same ids that's why you're getting the error

Comment: try using the `index` just for testing purposes and make sure the error is coming from this component and not from another one `.map((details, index) => { return <View key={index}> ...`

Comment: @AsafAviv both didn't worked

Comment: Then it looks like you forgot to add the `key prop` in another `component` that using `.map`

Comment: @AsafAviv I solved the problem. Thanks man. But still `TextInput` is not editable. why?

Comment: You are using the `value prop` which will always set the input field to this value, you will need to provide an `onChange`handler to each input and save the input value as the state

Comment: I have given `onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({first_name:text})}` for the first `TextInput`

Comment: @JithinVarghese You're not setting the right state. Your component relies on the `details.first_name` value but you're simply setting state of `first_name`.

If you're trying to create a dynamic array of forms, I'd suggest you use some form libraries like Formik https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/guides/react-native

Answer (score 1):

most probably you details may not have id field, due to which each time it gets undefined value and repeated through out you other children, the quick fix could be to use index that map gives as second parameter

> [].map((currentValue, index) => {});

about TextField, see you haven't told the TextField component to do something when a user edits to change it's value due to which the value is not being updated and hence the old value pops up which makes it seem like its not editable , please refer documentation to see the props that are required, https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html

Comment: It is working. But the `TextInput` is not editable.

Comment: @JithinVarghese The `TextInput` is not working because you need `onChangeText` to change the value of the `TextInput`. `TextInput` is a controlled component
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html

Answer (score 1):

Try to use array index for the key instead

```
{this.state.profileDetails.map((details, index) => //... )}
```

But keep in mind it's not the best for performance if the item order changes frequently. I would still suggest trying to make unique identifiers like the `id` field work and use those instead.

https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys